# DCount then OpenForm query in Access 2007 too slow

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2007

I have a number of buttons on a form which provide additional information to the user, each using DCount to see if there is any information to display and if so, opening a popup form to display it. All had been working well but now for one particular button, it is taking anything between 30 seconds and a minute to open the popup form, which is obviously unacceptable. Can't understand why it worked fine originally but has now gone so slow. All the other buttons still open their form in under a second. VBA is:

```
Private Sub btnNotes_Click()
  'open the popup notes for the current record, if there are associated records
  If DCount("ID","qlkpIDForNotes") = 0 Then
    MsgBox "There are no notes for this patient", vbOKOnly, "No information"
  Else
    DoCmd.OpenForm "fsubNotes",,,"ID = " & Me.displayID
  End If
End Sub
```

The table being queried has approx 40,000 rows, where the largest table checked for the other buttons has about 12,000. Have tried doing the DCount directly on the table rather than through a query, but doesn't make any difference. Also tried taking out a section of the data from the original table, copying about 1100 rows into a new table and testing on that. It still took 12 seconds to open.
Any ideas, anyone?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `DCount()` just to find out if there are *any* row in the table or query can be rather inefficient since `DCount()` will have to run the whole query and go through all records to return the total count just so you can compare that to `0`.

Depending on the complexity of that query, and the joins in it, and whether the joins use fields that have indexes or not, the cost of having to run that query can be exponentially proportional to the number of records in the underlying tables.

To solve your issue try this:

1. make sure there is an index on the underlying table's `ID` field in the `qlkpIDForNotes` query, and that all fields used in the `JOIN` or `WHERE` clauses also have indexes.
2. check if you can use the main underlying table or use a simplified query just to test if there are records that may be returned by `qlkpIDForNotes`, in short, you may not need to run that query in full just to find out if it would have some records.
3. use a separate function such as `HasAny()` below instead of `DCount()` when you only need to find out if a query returns any results:

```vb
'-------------------------------------------------------------------------'
' Returns whether the given query returned any result at all.             '
' Returns true if at least one record was returned.                       '
' To call:                                                                '
'   InUse = HasAny("SELECT TOP 1 ID FROM Product WHERE PartID=" & partID) '
'-------------------------------------------------------------------------'
Public Function HasAny(ByVal selectquery As String) As Boolean
    Dim db As DAO.database
    Dim rs As DAO.RecordSet
    Set db = CurrentDb
    Set rs = db.OpenRecordset(selectquery, dbOpenForwardOnly)
    HasAny = (rs.RecordCount > 0)
    rs.Close
    Set rs = Nothing
    Set db = Nothing
End Function
```

With this, you can simply rewrite your code as :

```
Private Sub btnNotes_Click()
  'open the popup notes for the current record, if there are associated records '
  If Not HasAny("qlkpIDForNotes") Then
    MsgBox "There are no notes for this patient", vbOKOnly, "No information"
  Else
    DoCmd.OpenForm "fsubNotes",,,"ID = " & Me.displayID
  End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Got an error message on the OpenRecordset that it has too few parameters. The first time I tried to run it, the database crashed and was put into an inconsistent state!

Comment: OK, got it to work with some editing. Didn't pass a string in, just used the actual SQL itself rather than a saved query name in the db.OpenRecordset and then it worked perfectly. Button click now opens in under a second again so many thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: @Chelle I had to simplify the code so the main part could be clearly understood. The actual code I use has a few more checks and error trapping to make it work robustly in production.

Comment: I'm not sure there is a need to create a UDF for this purpose, but I guess it's nice and tidy to call in multiple places. I would avoid using the **recordcount** though as without **.movelast** it's not always 100% accurate on DAO recordsets. More reliable is **rs.BOF And rs.EOF** that will always tell you whether a recordset has any data in the DAO environment.

Comment: @MattDonnan, recordcount is fine in this case, as the test is for if there are 0 or more than 0 records returned. recordcount will be at least 1 if records are returned, turning it into a simple comparison for the existence of data. [A Recordset or TableDef object with no records has a RecordCount property setting of 0](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb208624%28v=office.12%29.aspx)